# Where did Yayoi learn how to hunt ghosts?

Tags: dark-gathering

In the Wikia of *Dark Gathering*, it is explained that Yayoi developed a very high IQ of 160 after an accident, but it isn't explained how she learnt to hunt ghosts.

Where did Yayoi learn how to hunt ghosts?